# Смена размера шрифта текста

Tags: android

Здравствуйте! Хотелось бы узнать каким образом можно изменять размеры шрифта во всей программе, т.е чтобы имелась возможность увеличить или уменьшать размер шрифта на всех Activity одновременно. Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете всем элементам, где хотите изменить размер шрифта, задать размер `"@dimen/font_size"`, а затем изменять `font_size` на тот, который Вам необходимо.

Меняете в одном месте - меняется везде.

Comment: Задал для textview: android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" но выдал ошибку. С чем может быть связано?

Comment: @Вячеслав, а сам размер прописали?

Comment: Нет, но если нужно к примеру размер в 40 px то как его прописать?